# Rails 2.3 is not using right protocol ssl when using resource_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

On a rails 2.3 application i have this simple code

```
redirect_to resource_url(resource)
```

I make the request using a SSL connection (https) but it redirects to the non SSL version (http)

I checked and `resource_url` is throwing http without ssl.

How Rails knows if the protocol is https? My setup uses Nginx and 3 mongrels with load balancers.

I wonder if the issue is that my mongrel instances uses http.

Is there a way to let mongrel instances know that the connection to nginx was with ssl?

Is this really my issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused because nginx was configured with a load balancer. Basically the browser makes a SSL connection to Nginx, but nginx make a internal connection through http to the mongrel instances, and they don't know if the original connection was over SSL.

The solution is add this to the nginx config

```
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```